# SQL PHP : How to SELECT and fetch like this?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I'm know how to use basic SQL about select, join, fetch
but don't have idea how fetch like this to my website (see screenshot)

[image]

From screenshot It has column room_number too.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>room no.</td>
   <td>room name</td>
</tr>

<?php
$sql = SELECT * FROM si_room;
$query = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{  ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo ????? ; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo ?????; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?> 
</table>
```

**UPDATE :**

I try with this code

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM si_room";
    $querymain = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
    ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>room no.</td>
      <td>room_name</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    foreach ($querymain as $list_id => $list_data) 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> floor ".$list_data[0]['room_floor']."<br>"; 
        foreach ($list_data as $row)
        {                                       
            echo $row['room_no']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['room_name']."</td>";
         }
    } ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

but the result is

floor 2

201 | ROOM A

floor 2

202 | ROOM B

floor 3

301 | ROOM E

floor 3

302 | ROOM F

That's not I want.

Comment: Doesn't your `si_room` table need a column called `room_no` which will hold the three-digit room numbers?  (201, 202, 301, 302)

Comment: Yes it need sorry

Comment: It's not duplicate .  I Ask about abnormal  select

Comment: I don't see any abnormal parts.  Please add more clarity to your question.

Comment: There don't seem to be any problems with accessing your database information.  So it really comes down to "learning how to create an html table"  Time to start with some simple reading: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: if you'd *read* the linked answer, not just snatch a code from it, you'd have known that a field used for grouping should be listed first in the query.

Comment: @mickmackusa  wat????  I know table already.

Comment: @Your Common Sense - so I need to put room_floor at first field in sql statement?   "Select room_floor, room_name, room_no from si_room"  right?

Answer (score 2):

Luckily you are using PDO which already has this functionality for you, that can do exactly what you want - group the data based on some column.

[PDO can group results into the nested arrays](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP), based on the first field selected. So you need to list your list id as the first field in the field list , and then get your rows using `fetchAll()` with aforementioned fetch mode:

```
$sql = "select room_floor, room_name, room_no from si_room";
$building = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

and now you get a neat nested array where your rows are grouped by list id!

To make it output neatly you have to use two nested foreach operators

```
foreach ($building as $floor_no => $rooms)
{
     echo $floor_no."\n"; 
     foreach ($rooms as $row)
     {
         echo $row['room_name']."\n";
     }
}
```